# Results of gdalwarp from UTM32 to EPSG:4326 are not aligned?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, clip, gdalwarp, wgs84

I've a Sentinel 2 jp2 in UTM32 with this metadata:

```
Files: T32UQD_20200421T102021_TCI_60m.jp2
Size is 1830, 1830
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
        AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Origin = (699960.000000000000000,5900040.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (60.000000000000000,-60.000000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  699960.000, 5900040.000) ( 11d59'40.71"E, 53d12'43.17"N)
Lower Left  (  699960.000, 5790240.000) ( 11d55'40.15"E, 52d13'34.41"N)
Upper Right (  809760.000, 5900040.000) ( 13d38' 3.06"E, 53d 9'33.92"N)
Lower Right (  809760.000, 5790240.000) ( 13d31'51.72"E, 52d10'31.74"N)
Center      (  754860.000, 5845140.000) ( 12d46'18.91"E, 52d41'45.89"N)
```

I tried to warp this full jp2 by gdalwarp from UTM32 to EPSG:4326

```
gdalwarp T32UQD_20200421T102021_TCI_60m.jp2 -t_srs EPSG:4326 full_warp.tif
```

I also make a small subset from the original jp2 file with gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 798326.68347 5795956.80269 799609.577326 5794397.95642 T32UQD_20200421T102021_TCI_60m.jp2 crop.tif
```

And I project this small subset from UTM32 to EPSG:4326

```
 gdalwarp crop.tif -t_srs EPSG:4326 small_warp.tif -dstnodata 0
```

Then I overlay the full_warp.tif and small_warp.tif by QGIS 2.14.9. However, I realized that the **small_warp.tif** is not aligned on the **full_warp.tif**.

On the left hand side is the **full_warp.tif** and on the right hand side is **small_warp.tif** overlays on **full_warp.tif**.

[image]

I cannot find out the reason here? Can someone give an idea?

**Update 1:**

The gdalinfo of the crop.tif by **gdal_translate** show it is aligned (I don't see the geo bounds and pixel resolutions with odd numbers)

```
gdalinfo crop.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: crop.tif
Size is 21, 26
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Origin = (798300.000000000000000,5796000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (60.000000000000000,-60.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  798300.000, 5796000.000) ( 13d22' 8.43"E, 52d14' 0.35"N)
Lower Left  (  798300.000, 5794440.000) ( 13d22' 3.48"E, 52d13'10.01"N)
Upper Right (  799560.000, 5796000.000) ( 13d23'14.66"E, 52d13'57.89"N)
Lower Right (  799560.000, 5794440.000) ( 13d23' 9.69"E, 52d13' 7.55"N)
Center      (  798930.000, 5795220.000) ( 13d22'39.06"E, 52d13'33.95"N)
```

**Update 2**: I tried to use gdalwarp with -tr (values come from full_warp.tif) by Python Gdal: dataset.GetGeoTransform() and -tap options

```
gdalwarp crop.tif -t_srs EPSG:4326 small_warp.tif -dstnodata 0 -tap -tr 0.0007161230037719291 -0.0007161230037719291
```

The result is still misaligned by row and column as below when overlaying small_warp.tif on full_warp.tif

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that the edges of your crop aligned exactly on the pixel boundary?

Comment: @IanTurton I think this is done by gdal_translate under neath? It will align my given bounding box in UTM32  to what it wants to calculate. I never thought gdal user needs to align the bbox.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the pixels start at the edge of the requested bbox and continue across from there - that is how rasters work

Comment: @IanTurton: I checked the result of gdal_translate for the given bbox (crop.tif) by gdalinfo. It is aligned with the original JP2 file. Coordinates in UTM 32. Clipped file: Upper Left  (  798300.000, 5796000.000). Original file: Upper Left  (  699960.000, 5900040.000)

Comment: You asked for 798326.68347 5795956.80269 799609.577326 5794397.95642 - so something is wrong

Comment: Gdalwarp has a -tap option "target aligned pixels" that may help https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html.

Comment: I recommend also to set the output resolution with the -tr switch. Otherwise the outputs from gdalwarp may lead to slightly different pixel sizes.

Comment: @user30184: actually -tap must need to use with -tr. I updated my result in the description with your suggestions to make sure both full_warp.tif and smal_warp.tiff have same pixel resolutions. But these 2 warped files are still misaligned a bit on QGIS.

Comment: A link to a test image would be nice.

Comment: @user30184 you could download this small scene from here https://easyupload.io/owtgy5 (3 MB)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post the suggestions from 
Even Rouault from gdal-dev mailing list:

> When you don't specify any target extent or resolution, gdalwarp guesses them from the input raster georeferencing and target SRS. It doesn't try to align on any particular resolution
>
> You may want to use the -tr and -tap switches to specify a target resolution, and constraint the extents to be aligned on it.
>
> Another reason for the misalignment is that you use the default nearest resampling. Using -r cubic could likely improve things
>
> To get perfectly overlapping images, you may also need to specify -et 0

From his idea (same as https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184 with **-tap** option), I tried these commands and results are aligned on Qgis

```
gdalwarp -tr 0.0007161230037719291 -0.0007161230037719291 T32UQD_20200421T102021_TCI_60m.jp2 full_warp.tif -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata 0 -tap

gdalwarp -tr 0.0007161230037719291 -0.0007161230037719291 crop.tif small_warp.tif -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata 0 -tap
```

Illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucwkE.png